# How to make a drop-down menu scrollable

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a drop-down menu in a navbar. I have done this, but the list of items is too long to fit on the page (the bottom of the list is hidden) so I therefore need to make the list scrollable. As of now, when the menu is "open" and I scroll, it scrolls the page behind the menu rather than the menu. Please help me figure this out! Below I have posted a bit of my HTML and CSS as it pertains to this drop down menu.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle scrollable-menu" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">INSTRUMENTS</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        {% for instrument in instruments %}
                            <a href="{% url 'instruments:individual_display' instrument.id %}" class="dropdown-item"> {{ instrument.name }} </a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </li>

.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: There's a decent solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534440/how-to-set-height-for-the-drop-down-of-select-box

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `overflow-y: auto` or `overflow-y: scroll` yet?  Don't have the time to work on an example at the moment, but that should point you in the right direction.

You can find a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802877/overflow-y-scroll-not-working-showing-style-but-cannot-be-scrolled) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the correct selector.dropdown-menu is the correct selector if not solved then try `overflow:auto;`
if not solved then try this [example](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/MaKa3)